# DropWizard - Unable to change the default pattern of request in access log

Tags: dropwizard

In dropwizard, how can we change the default pattern of requests that are written in access.log file? Eg. I wanted to add milliseconds parameter also in timestamp field of requests. I am able to make changes in pattern of service.log file using yaml file(configuration file) but not in access.log. Don't know why?

Please help in this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I know for the other logging appenders you can specify a `logFormat` in the yaml config, but not sure if it works for the `requestLog`.

If the above doesn't work, keep an eye on this ticket on github: [experimenting with a configurable pattern for access requests using logback-access](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/370)